# Using RoleManager ApplicationRole to insert new role

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a method to add new roles like:

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRole(ApplicationRoleModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var role in model.RoleList)
                {
                    var roleExists = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role.Name);
                    if (roleExists) continue;
                    var createRole = _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
                }
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
```

So as you can see I use `foreach` clause to access model who have `IEnumerable` of `ApplicationRole` like:

```
 public class ApplicationRoleModel : ClaimsToRoleModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<ApplicationRole> RoleList { get; set; }    
    }
```

So as you can see in foreach I can access to `role.Name` of `RoleList (ApplicationRole)`, I tested it with postman and it works, it added new Role successfull, now instead postman I want to create view to create new role so I try:

```
@page
@model Security.Dto.Models.ApplicationRoleModel
      <form asp-controller="security" asp-action="CreateRole" method="post">
                <h4>Create new Role</h4>
                <hr />
                <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="RoleList.Name">Role Name</label>
                    <input asp-for="RoleList.Name" class="form-control" />
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>
            </form>
```

But when I try to compile project it return:

> 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for
>   'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

So, how can I access to `Name` property of `ApplicationRole` to assign to model from view? Regards

Note: I also try to access it on my view like:

```
@for(Int32 i = 0; i < this.Model.RoleList.Count; i++ ) {
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="RoleList[i].Name">Role Name</label>
                <input asp-for="RoleList[i].Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            }
```

But I get:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type
>   'IEnumerable'

Comment: `RoleList.[ToList()|ToArray()]` first. The index. You cannot index an `IEnumerable`

Comment: I don't understand your answer, can you explain more? I try to use `RoleList.[ToList()|ToArray()]` in my view as your comment but it no works @dcg

Comment: NO, the `.[ToList()|ToArray()]` means either you use `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()`. After that you can index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model in your view is `IEnumerable<ApplicationRole>` but you attempting to create controls for a single instance of `ApplicationRole`

You could use `List<ApplicationRole>` instead of `IEnumerable<ApplicationRole>`in your model and use jquery to add role lists as below

Model:

```
public class ApplicationRoleModel : ClaimsToRoleModel
{
    public List<ApplicationRole> RoleList { get; set; }    
}
```

View:

```
@page
@model Security.Dto.Models.ApplicationRoleModel

<form asp-controller="security" asp-action="CreateRole" method="post">

<h4>Create new Role</h4>
<hr />
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="form-group" id="item-list">
    <label>Role Name</label>
    <input asp-for="RoleList[0].Name" class="form-control items" />
</div>
<a href="#" id="add">Add another</a>//click to add
<br />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>

</form>

@section Scripts {
<script>
$(function () {

   $("#add").click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var i = ($(".items").length);
       var n = '<input class="form-control items" name="RoleList[' + i + '].Name" />' 
       $("#item-list").append(n);
   });

});
</script>
}
```